# How legend-entry can be possible in Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I want to use legend-entry for straight line & dotted line.

```
\begin{figure}[htp]
{\small
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}

\draw [color=black, fill=gray!50] ( 0.2 , 1.975 )-- ( 0.3 , 2.05 )-- ( 0.4 , 2.185 )-- ( 0.5 , 2.32 ) --( 0.5 , 2.2222 )-- ( 0.4 , 1.8 )-- ( 0.3 , 1.25 )--( 0.2 , 1.1111 )--cycle;
\draw (0.2,0) -- (10.3,0);

\draw (0.2,5.1) -- (10.3,5.1);

\draw (0.2,0)-- (0.2,5.1);

\draw (10.3,0)-- (10.3,5.1);
\draw ( 0.2 , 1.975 )-- ( 0.3 , 2.05 )-- ( 0.4 , 2.185 )-- ( 0.5 , 2.32 )-- ( 0.6 , 2.445 )-- ( 0.7 , 2.56 )-- ( 0.8 , 2.66 )-- ( 0.9 , 2.745 )-- ( 1.0 , 2.825 )-- ( 1.1 , 2.9 )-- ( 1.2 , 2.965 )-- ( 1.3 , 3.025 )-- ( 1.4 , 3.08 )-- ( 1.5 , 3.13 )-- ( 1.6 , 3.18 )-- ( 1.7 , 3.22 )-- ( 1.8 , 3.26 )-- ( 1.9 , 3.3 )-- ( 2.0 , 3.335 )-- ( 2.1 , 3.37 )-- ( 2.2 , 3.4 )-- ( 2.3 , 3.43 )-- ( 2.4 , 3.46 )-- ( 2.5 , 3.485 )-- ( 2.6 , 3.51 )-- ( 2.7 , 3.535 )-- ( 2.8 , 3.56 )-- ( 2.9 , 3.58 )-- ( 3.0 , 3.6 )-- ( 3.1 , 3.62 )-- ( 3.2 , 3.64 )-- ( 3.3 , 3.66 )-- ( 3.4 , 3.675 )-- ( 3.5 , 3.695 )-- ( 3.6 , 3.71 )-- ( 3.7 , 3.725 )-- ( 3.8 , 3.74 )-- ( 3.9 , 3.755 )-- ( 4.0 , 3.77 )-- ( 4.1 , 3.78 )-- ( 4.2 , 3.795 )-- ( 4.3 , 3.81 )-- ( 4.4 , 3.82 )-- ( 4.5 , 3.835 )-- ( 4.6 , 3.845 )-- ( 4.7 , 3.855 )-- ( 4.8 , 3.865 )-- ( 4.9 , 3.88 )-- ( 5.0 , 3.89 )-- ( 5.1 , 3.9 )-- ( 5.2 , 3.91 )-- ( 5.3 , 3.915 )-- ( 5.4 , 3.925 )-- ( 5.5 , 3.935 )-- ( 5.6 , 3.945 )-- ( 5.7 , 3.955 )-- ( 5.8 , 3.96 )-- ( 5.9 , 3.97 )-- ( 6.0 , 3.98 )-- ( 6.1 , 3.985 )-- ( 6.2 , 3.995 )-- ( 6.3 , 4.0 )-- ( 6.4 , 4.01 )-- ( 6.5 , 4.015 )-- ( 6.6 , 4.02 )-- ( 6.7 , 4.03 )-- ( 6.8 , 4.035 )-- ( 6.9 , 4.045 )-- ( 7.0 , 4.05 )-- ( 7.1 , 4.055 )-- ( 7.2 , 4.06 )-- ( 7.3 , 4.07 )-- ( 7.4 , 4.075 )-- ( 7.5 , 4.08 )-- ( 7.6 , 4.085 )-- ( 7.7 , 4.09 )-- ( 7.8 , 4.095 )-- ( 7.9 , 4.1 )-- ( 8.0 , 4.105 )-- ( 8.1 , 4.11 )-- ( 8.2 , 4.115 )-- ( 8.3 , 4.12 )-- ( 8.4 , 4.125 )-- ( 8.5 , 4.13 )-- ( 8.6 , 4.135 )-- ( 8.7 , 4.14 )-- ( 8.8 , 4.145 )-- ( 8.9 , 4.15 )-- ( 9.0 , 4.155 )-- ( 9.1 , 4.16 )-- ( 9.2 , 4.165 )-- ( 9.3 , 4.17 )-- ( 9.4 , 4.175 )-- ( 9.5 , 4.175 )-- ( 9.6 , 4.18 )-- ( 9.7 , 4.185 )-- ( 9.8 , 4.19 )-- ( 9.9 , 4.195 )-- ( 10.0 , 4.195 );




\draw[dotted] ( 0.2 , 1.1111 )-- ( 0.3 , 1.25 )-- ( 0.4 , 1.8 )-- ( 0.5 , 2.2222 )-- ( 0.6 , 2.551 )-- ( 0.7 , 2.8125 )-- ( 0.8 , 3.0247 )-- ( 0.9 , 3.2 )-- ( 1.0 , 3.3471 )-- ( 1.1 , 3.4722 )-- ( 1.2 , 3.5799 )-- ( 1.3 , 3.6735 )-- ( 1.4 , 3.7556 )-- ( 1.5 , 3.8281 )-- ( 1.6 , 3.8927 )-- ( 1.7 , 3.9506 )-- ( 1.8 , 4.0028 )-- ( 1.9 , 4.05 )-- ( 2.0 , 4.093 )-- ( 2.1 , 4.1322 )-- ( 2.2 , 4.1682 )-- ( 2.3 , 4.2014 )-- ( 2.4 , 4.232 )-- ( 2.5 , 4.2604 )-- ( 2.6 , 4.2867 )-- ( 2.7 , 4.3112 )-- ( 2.8 , 4.3341 )-- ( 2.9 , 4.3556 )-- ( 3.0 , 4.3757 )-- ( 3.1 , 4.3945 )-- ( 3.2 , 4.4123 )-- ( 3.3 , 4.4291 )-- ( 3.4 , 4.4449 )-- ( 3.5 , 4.4599 )-- ( 3.6 , 4.4741 )-- ( 3.7 , 4.4875 )-- ( 3.8 , 4.5003 )-- ( 3.9 , 4.5125 )-- ( 4.0 , 4.5241 )-- ( 4.1 , 4.5351 )-- ( 4.2 , 4.5457 )-- ( 4.3 , 4.5558 )-- ( 4.4 , 4.5654 )-- ( 4.5 , 4.5747 )-- ( 4.6 , 4.5835 )-- ( 4.7 , 4.592 )-- ( 4.8 , 4.6002 )-- ( 4.9 , 4.608 )-- ( 5.0 , 4.6155 )-- ( 5.1 , 4.6228 )-- ( 5.2 , 4.6298 )-- ( 5.3 , 4.6365 )-- ( 5.4 , 4.643 )-- ( 5.5 , 4.6492 )-- ( 5.6 , 4.6553 )-- ( 5.7 , 4.6611 )-- ( 5.8 , 4.6668 )-- ( 5.9 , 4.6722 )-- ( 6.0 , 4.6775 )-- ( 6.1 , 4.6826 )-- ( 6.2 , 4.6876 )-- ( 6.3 , 4.6924 )-- ( 6.4 , 4.697 )-- ( 6.5 , 4.7016 )-- ( 6.6 , 4.7059 )-- ( 6.7 , 4.7102 )-- ( 6.8 , 4.7143 )-- ( 6.9 , 4.7184 )-- ( 7.0 , 4.7223 )-- ( 7.1 , 4.7261 )-- ( 7.2 , 4.7298 )-- ( 7.3 , 4.7334 )-- ( 7.4 , 4.7369 )-- ( 7.5 , 4.7403 )-- ( 7.6 , 4.7436 )-- ( 7.7 , 4.7469 )-- ( 7.8 , 4.75 )-- ( 7.9 , 4.7531 )-- ( 8.0 , 4.7561 )-- ( 8.1 , 4.7591 )-- ( 8.2 , 4.7619 )-- ( 8.3 , 4.7647 )-- ( 8.4 , 4.7675 )-- ( 8.5 , 4.7701 )-- ( 8.6 , 4.7728 )-- ( 8.7 , 4.7753 )-- ( 8.8 , 4.7778 )-- ( 8.9 , 4.7802 )-- ( 9.0 , 4.7826 )-- ( 9.1 , 4.785 )-- ( 9.2 , 4.7873 )-- ( 9.3 , 4.7895 )-- ( 9.4 , 4.7917 )-- ( 9.5 , 4.7938 )-- ( 9.6 , 4.7959 )-- ( 9.7 , 4.798 )-- ( 9.8 , 4.8 )-- ( 9.9 , 4.802 )-- ( 10.0 , 4.8039 );

\draw (0.0,1.11) node{$A$};

\draw (0.65 , 2.25) node{$B$};

\draw (0.0,1.98) node{$C$};


\draw (5,-.9) node{$r \rightarrow$};

\draw (-1.6,3) node{$\delta$};

\draw (-1.6,3.32) node{$\uparrow$};

\end{tikzpicture}

}

\label{fig1}

\end{figure}
```

When I use the following code, shape of the figure changes (becomes square).

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[ylabel=$\delta$,xlabel=$r$,  legend style={at={(0.95,0.05)},anchor=south east}]

\addplot[no marks,dotted] coordinates {( 0.2 , 1.1111 ) ( 0.3 , 1.25 ) ( 0.4 , 1.8 ) ( 0.5 , 2.2222 ) ( 0.6 , 2.551 ) ( 0.7 , 2.8125 ) ( 0.8 , 3.0247 ) ( 0.9 , 3.2 ) ( 1.0 , 3.3471 ) ( 1.1 , 3.4722 ) ( 1.2 , 3.5799 ) ( 1.3 , 3.6735 ) ( 1.4 , 3.7556 ) ( 1.5 , 3.8281 ) ( 1.6 , 3.8927 ) ( 1.7 , 3.9506 ) ( 1.8 , 4.0028 ) ( 1.9 , 4.05 ) ( 2.0 , 4.093 ) ( 2.1 , 4.1322 ) ( 2.2 , 4.1682 ) ( 2.3 , 4.2014 ) ( 2.4 , 4.232 ) ( 2.5 , 4.2604 ) ( 2.6 , 4.2867 ) ( 2.7 , 4.3112 ) ( 2.8 , 4.3341 ) ( 2.9 , 4.3556 ) ( 3.0 , 4.3757 ) ( 3.1 , 4.3945 ) ( 3.2 , 4.4123 ) ( 3.3 , 4.4291 ) ( 3.4 , 4.4449 ) ( 3.5 , 4.4599 ) ( 3.6 , 4.4741 ) ( 3.7 , 4.4875 ) ( 3.8 , 4.5003 ) ( 3.9 , 4.5125 ) ( 4.0 , 4.5241 ) ( 4.1 , 4.5351 ) ( 4.2 , 4.5457 ) ( 4.3 , 4.5558 ) ( 4.4 , 4.5654 ) ( 4.5 , 4.5747 ) ( 4.6 , 4.5835 ) ( 4.7 , 4.592 ) ( 4.8 , 4.6002 ) ( 4.9 , 4.608 ) ( 5.0 , 4.6155 ) ( 5.1 , 4.6228 ) ( 5.2 , 4.6298 )( 5.3 , 4.6365 ) ( 5.4 , 4.643 ) ( 5.5 , 4.6492 ) ( 5.6 , 4.6553 ) ( 5.7 , 4.6611 ) ( 5.8 , 4.6668 ) ( 5.9 , 4.6722 ) ( 6.0 , 4.6775 ) ( 6.1 , 4.6826 ) ( 6.2 , 4.6876 ) ( 6.3 , 4.6924 ) ( 6.4 , 4.697 ) ( 6.5 , 4.7016 ) ( 6.6 , 4.7059 ) ( 6.7 , 4.7102 ) ( 6.8 , 4.7143 ) ( 6.9 , 4.7184 ) ( 7.0 , 4.7223 ) ( 7.1 , 4.7261 ) ( 7.2 , 4.7298 ) ( 7.3 , 4.7334 ) ( 7.4 , 4.7369 ) ( 7.5 , 4.7403 ) ( 7.6 , 4.7436 ) ( 7.7 , 4.7469 ) ( 7.8 , 4.75 ) ( 7.9 , 4.7531 ) ( 8.0 , 4.7561 ) ( 8.1 , 4.7591 ) ( 8.2 , 4.7619 ) ( 8.3 , 4.7647 ) ( 8.4 , 4.7675 ) ( 8.5 , 4.7701 ) ( 8.6 , 4.7728 ) ( 8.7 , 4.7753 ) ( 8.8 , 4.7778 ) ( 8.9 , 4.7802 ) ( 9.0 , 4.7826 ) ( 9.1 , 4.785 ) ( 9.2 , 4.7873 ) ( 9.3 , 4.7895 ) ( 9.4 , 4.7917 ) ( 9.5 , 4.7938 ) ( 9.6 , 4.7959 ) ( 9.7 , 4.798 ) ( 9.8 , 4.8 ) ( 9.9 , 4.802 ) ( 10.0 , 4.8039 )};


\addlegendentry{Style 1}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: I think you don't need to be introduced to the [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) concept. Plus legend is offered in `pgfplots` do you want to fake it in TikZ ? Also it feels like there is something wrong with Matrix (the movie) today. http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/68299/adding-a-legend-entry-to-a-plot

Comment: I do not want to use marks (0,0.2,..) on x axis and y axis.

Comment: @user12290: You can just add `xtick=\empty, ytick=\empty,` to the options in percusse's answer to your last question to remove the ticks.

Comment: I suggest you to have a look to [Using a pgfplots-style legend in a plain-old tikzpicture](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/54794/13304) and [Legend in tikzpicture](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/62262/13304).

Comment: To set the aspect ratio to match that of your data, use the option `axis equal image`.